# I want keep history on sdcard,!!Only one time create a File object, History failure

Tags: java, android, file, object, android-edittext

I want keep history on sdcard, which typed on edittext. but my code generates new File object everytime i call.
when Im in the session code is working, but recall "createExternalStorageFile()" , previous history gone, same file new history. How can i fix?

```
public void createExternalStorageFile() {
    try {
            File  myFile = new File("/sdcard/" + tmp );

            if ( !myFile.exists()  ){
                myFile.createNewFile();
            } else{

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(messageHistoryText.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();

            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below, it works for me:

```
public void createExternalStorageFile() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        String fileName = "out.txt"; 
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(root, fileName);
        if (file.canWrite()) {
            try {
                boolean append = file.exists();
                FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(file, append);
                PrintWriter logFileWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile);
                logFileWriter.append(messageHistoryText.getText());
                logFileWriter.flush();
                logFileWriter.close();
                outFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("LOGGER", "" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("LOGGER", "Couldn't write log file!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("LOGGER", "External storage is not mounted!");
    }
}
```